# How can i combine (mercurial) changesets from two jobs in jenkins

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

so that instead of getting them individually on a per job basis, get them all in one report, and can also report them via Email-ext report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Multiple SCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin)